# Angular | Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular

I have a problem with Angular, I'm trying to get data from my json with *ngFor but I get this error:

Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

How can I go about solving it? Below is my code.

my service.ts

```
  getChannels(): Observable<Channel[]> {
    const url = this.urlGet;
    return this.http.get<Channel[]>(url)
  }
```

my component.ts

```
channels: Channel [] = [];

constructor(private channelService: ChannelService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getChannel();
  }
 getChannel() {
    this.channelService.getChannels().subscribe(response => this.channels = response)
  }
```

json from api

```
{
  "result": 
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Channel 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Channel 2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Channel 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

my component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let channel of channels">
   {{channel.name}}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getChannels function should look like this:

```
getChannel() {
    this.channelService.getChannels().subscribe(response => this.channels = response.result)
  }
```

You were assigning the whole object instead of the array inside.

In the future you should use the correct type for the returnvalue of the function with the http call:

```
  getChannels(): Observable<{result:Channel[]}> {
    const url = this.urlGet;
    return this.http.get<{result:Channel[]}>(url)
  }
```